# Migrate new database with exceeding old database value

Tags: mysql, database, data-migration

I need to migrate the exceeding database value with new one. I have two database like test and test new. I create the both database with same data. I made the all changes in test now I need migrate that changes in test new without affecting existing value.

If table schema is different, how will I then go about doing this? In my prev job, what I      did was import data (in my case, from Access) into my destination (MySQL) leaving       table structures, then use SQL to select data and manipulate as required into final destination tables.

in my case, where I don't have documentation for the old database, and the columns was not named correctly, e.g. it uses say `'field1'`, `'field2'` etc. I needed to trace from the application code what the columns mean. Is there any better way? Also, sometimes columns contain multiple values in delimited data, is reading code the only way?

Comment: you wanted to apend data from test new to test rite?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you know what to do, but are just not keen to do it.

If there is no documentation then it makes sense that you will have to go to the code to figure out what it does. Regarding porting it across you will most likely have to write custom scripts that pull the data, manipulate it and insert it into the new table based on the new structure.

There are some tools to generate migration scripts - i.e. scripts that generate inserts for all your data. I think mysql workbench does it, but it most likely won't be sufficient since your tables have different structures.